# the first five characters

Tags: text-processing

I need to copy the first five characters from an output file, 25 lines in all, and copy that output to a file. also it might be nice to remove blank or null entries in the output.

Answer (score 3):

`head` could be useful here:

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each file; with the leading '-', print all but the last K bytes of each file
```

Comment: This copies *bytes*, not characters. Try it with your name.

Answer (score 2):

`cut -c5` cuts the first 5 characters of each line in its input. If you want to restrict the number of lines to 25, use `head -n25`:

```
cut -c5 file | head -n25
```

Comment: Actually I want to keep the first 5 characters and copy them to a 2nd file, would this work as well?

Comment: @user177073: Yes, it does not change the original file. It output to standard output, if you want to create a file, just use redirection: `cut -c5 file | head -n25 > output`.

Comment: Ok here is what I came up with;
cut -c5 /home/user/Desktop/parse2.txt' | > /home/user/Desktop/symbols.txt
it creates the file, but the file is empty

Comment: This does not copy the first five characters.

Comment: @user177073: Remove the `|` before the `>`.

Comment: +1 for `cut -c`, which performs true _character_-based cutting (rather than _byte_-based), but I think the intent was to _extract_ the first 5 chars. from the _first line only_, i.e., `head -n1 file | cut -c1-5`; to then include the 24 following lines and remove empty ones among them requires additional work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed                         \
  -e 's/\(^\w\{5\}\).*/\1/' \
  -e '26,$d'                \
  -e '/^$/d'                \
  input_file > output_file
```

The first part matches five characters at the beginning of the line,
prints them and discards the rest. The second part ensures that only
the first 25 lines are printed. And the last part removes empty lines.

Comment: Kudos for a comprehensive, single-utility solution. To make it POSIX-compliant, replace `\w` with `[[:alnum:]_]`. To also eliminate blank (all-whitespace) lines, replace `/^$/` with `/^[[:blank:]]*$/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat inputfile | head -c 5 > outputfile
```

This should redirect the output to the file.

If you wish to remove the whitespaces then filter the contents of the file, i.e remove the spaces before you extract the first five characters.

```
cat inputfile | tr -d ' ' | head -c 5 > outputfile
```

You may also use the following format of `tr` to achieve the same effect.

`cat inputfile | tr -d [:space:] | head -c 5 > outputfile`

`tr -d [:space:]` removes all spaces from the text that has been piped to this command.

Stick to the above solution if you want the truncation for only the first 5 characters of the file.

Now if you wish to do this for each and every line of your file then follow this:

`cat inputfile | sed -e 's/ //g' | awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}' > outputfile`

or

`sed -e 's/ //g'  < inputfile | awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}' > outputfile`

Explaination: `sed -e 's/ //g'` removes all spaces and `awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}'` prints the first 5 characters of everyline.

Comment: why the downvote? This gives the desired output. Atlease mention what was wrong.

Comment: Instead of `cat file | command` you can often use `command file` (the downvote is not from me).

Comment: I could have easily resorted to a input redirection, just to make the procedure clear to the asker i've used the `cat` command. 

I have edited the answer including the new input redirection

Comment: I think I phrased this wrong, by the way all your answers were very helpful, but what I should have asked was, how do you copy the first work in a line, the word in this case is a stock symbol from yahoo finance, wht I really need it seems is a SED or AWK parse that will pull the first word up to its end, then when it sees a null or empty space it goes to the next line. Right now I'm using this sed -e 's/ //g' < /home/user/Desktop/file3.txt | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' > /home/user/Desktop/file4.txt, it works but it its buggy and I do realize I changed the 5 to a 4. your thoughts?

Comment: @user177073 if you need to extract only the first word from each line then the code is `awk '{print $1}' /home/user/Desktop/file3.txt > /home/user/Desktop/file4.txt`

Comment: If this is still not what you need, then please include a sample input and sample output in your question. Would be easier for us. :)

Comment: so was the code in the comment the required thing?

Comment: sed -e 's/ //g' < /home/user/Desktop/file1.txt | awk '{print $1}' > /home/user/Desktop/file2.txt

Comment: I've tried this modification, doesn't work, sed -e 's/ //g' < /home/user/Desktop/file1.txt | awk '{print $1}' > /home/user/Desktop/file2.txt I'll paste in the some of the resultant file.

Comment: right now the out put looks like this debal:  STXSStereotaxis,Inc.7.34Up3.1417,323,561Chart,Profile,  All I need is the STXS par the rest is of no use

Comment: pipe the output of the previous commad to the following awk command, `sed -e 's/ //g' < /home/user/Desktop/file1.txt | awk -F "," '{print $1}'` > /home/user/Desktop/file2.txt

Comment: Thank You this cuts it down to the first comma, the page seems to be a tab space after the first word is there a way to get it to recognize this? heres the present output to dile "STXSStereotaxis" , I'll keep looking for the syntax in awk, Thanks again for your help

Comment: I think I might have found something, the FIELDWIDTHS